# Código barras IReport, barcode 2int5

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Construí um layout novo personalizado que recebemos por webservice

- Usei o Ireport 6.3.0
- Quando vou imprimir o código de barras fica distorcido
- A variável que o código de barras recebe o valor é do tipo String
- O valor da variável de teste é  "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
- O valor de teste do código é  "00000.00000 00000.000000 00000.000000 0 00000000000000"
- Segundo a especificação dos bancos o código de barras deve ter "altura de 13mm" e largura de 103mm.

Já tentei varias combinações e ainda nada!
Alguém puder dar umas dicas
Tem uma imagem em anexo para ajudar a entender o que estou tentando fazer[image: Códigos barra 2int5]

Comment: Boa tarde @MarceloFerreira, estou tendo o mesmo problema que você, por um acaso conseguiu resolver?